# asyncio.Queue Stuck With 1 Coroutine Adding to Queue, 1 Coroutine Getting from Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-asyncio, coroutine

In my simple asyncio code below, the app has one task `self.add_item_loop_task` continuously adding an integer to the `asyncio.Queue` named `self.queue`, while a second task `self.get_item_loop_task` continuously waits for something to be added to the queue and `print` it out.

However, this app only prints out `0` once when I run it, and gets stuck there. I believe the loop in `self.get_item_loop_task` is not proceeding. Why is this happening?

```
import asyncio

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

    async def start(self):
        self.add_item_loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.add_item_loop())
        self.get_item_loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.get_item_loop())
        await asyncio.wait(
            [
                self.add_item_loop_task,
                self.get_item_loop_task,
            ]
        )

    async def stop(self):
        self.add_item_loop_task.cancel()
        self.get_item_loop_task.cancel()

    async def add_item_loop(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            await self.queue.put(i)
            i += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def get_item_loop(self):
        while True:
            item = await self.queue.get()
            print(item)


app = App()
try:
    asyncio.run(app.start())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    asyncio.run(app.stop())
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by some dubious implementation details of asyncio. When you say  `self.queue = asyncio.Queue()` this will actually create an event loop if one does not already exist. Meanwhile, when you call `asyncio.run()` it will *always* create a new event loop. This means if you create a queue before you call `asyncio.run()` you can get some strange behavior because there are two event loops, the one that your queue uses and the one that `asyncio.run` is using.

You can fix this issue by moving the creation of `App` into a coroutine function that you pass in to `asyncio.run()` like below. Doing this your application works as intended.

```
async def main():
    app = App()
    await app.start()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Matt Fowler explained the code is creating two simultaneous event loops. One created when initializing the class and the second one when running `asyncio.run(main())`.

You can simply move `self.queue = asyncio.Queue()` from the `def __init__(self)` method to the beginning `async def start(self)` method. The newly created `asyncio.Queue()` object will be available to both tasks.

The following code works:

```
import asyncio

class App:
# def __init__(self):
#     self.queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def start(self):
    # self.queue in the following line will be available to both tasks
    self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
    self.add_item_loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.add_item_loop())
    self.get_item_loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.get_item_loop())
    await asyncio.wait(
        [
            self.add_item_loop_task,
            self.get_item_loop_task,
        ]
    )

async def stop(self):
    self.add_item_loop_task.cancel()
    self.get_item_loop_task.cancel()

async def add_item_loop(self):
    i = 0
    while True:
        await self.queue.put(i)
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def get_item_loop(self):
    while True:
        item = await self.queue.get()
        print(item)

app = App()
try:
  asyncio.run(app.start())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  asyncio.run(app.stop())
```

Comment: Sounds like a good alternative! Thanks!